# How to spread data with r

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have my data like that

```
windspeed      month
1.2             Jan
2               Feb
3.5             Mar
2.6             Apr
5.9             Jun
2.5             Jul
```

I want to get this kind of data

```
Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr    Jun   Jul  
1.2    2     3.5    2.6   5.9   2.5
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

just base R (even though `setNames` belongs to `stats` package in fact):

```
setNames(dat$windspeed, dat$month)
Jan Feb Mar Apr Jun Jul 
1.2 2.0 3.5 2.6 5.9 2.5
```

yes there is (are) a way(s), here is one:

```
as.data.frame(t(setNames(dat$windspeed, dat$month)))
  Jan Feb Mar Apr Jun Jul
1 1.2   2 3.5 2.6 5.9 2.5
```

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
t(unstack(DF, windspeed ~ month))

    Apr Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar
res 2.6   2 1.2 2.5 5.9 3.5
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some very useful packages as well in R, suitable for such operations like `reshape`, `data.table`, `tidyr`

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

dcast.data.table(melt(setDT(data), id.vars = "month"), variable ~ month)
#   variable Apr Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar
#1: windspeed 2.6   2 1.2 2.5 5.9 3.5

library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
spread(melt(data), month, value)

#   variable Apr Feb Jan Jul Jun Mar
#1 windspeed 2.6   2 1.2 2.5 5.9 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
DF <- data.frame(windspeed=c(1.2, 2, 3.5, 2.6, 5.9, 2.5), month=c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun', 'Jul'))
DF <- t(DF)
colnames(DF) = DF[2, ]
DF <- DF[1,]
DF
```

Gives you

```
 Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   Jun   Jul 
"1.2" "2.0" "3.5" "2.6" "5.9" "2.5"
```